# Is it possible to remove one or more vectors from S to create a basis for V

Tags: linear-algebra

If a set S of vectors spans a vector space V, then is it possible to remove one or more vectors from S to create a basis for V ?

I think that this is a tricky question as I am not sure whether S contains a dummy vector that is linearly dependent on the one(s) you left out. In which case it will possible to remove those vectors.

But If for example I have a set {x,y,z} spanning a vector space. Taking y away wont help my set span the same vector space. Right ?

Comment: Assuming you are speaking about finite dimensional vector spaces, then you can work inductively.  If there is a linear dependence between the vectors, you can use it to eliminate any one of the vectors that appears with a non-zero coefficient.

Comment: Should say:  I don't understand your $\{x,y,z\}$ example.  If those are linearly independent, then they already form a basis of the vector space they span.  If they are linearly dependent, then you can remove at least one without changing the span.

Comment: I am a bit confused as I have a question asking me whether "If a set S of vectors spans a vector space V, then it is possible to remove one or more vectors from S to create a basis for V." is true or false. To which I replied true as spanning can be done with additional vectors that aren't really the basis of the vector space. Right ?

Comment: I agree with your conclusion (again, assuming, for simplicity,  that we are speaking of finite dimensional vector spaces) but I do not understand your argument.  In my first argument, I suggested that you prove it via induction.

Comment: Here's my argument better reworded: If I have $(u_1, u_2,u_3,u_4)$ spanning a vector space. Then deleting $u_4$ is not going to impede my ability to span the same vector space **IF** only $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ are the basis. Also, If a set S of vectors is linearly independent in a vector space V, then it is possible to add zero or more vectors to S to create a basis for V.

Comment: That's not an argument.  For the first part, you just give a single example that works out the way you want.  And the second part has nothing to do with what you were asked to prove.  Seriously, do it by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you are working with finite dimensional vector spaces.  Let $V$ be the vector space in question and let $d=\dim V$.

The claim we want to prove:  any finite collection of vectors in $V$ which spans $V$ contains a basis.

Proof by induction on the number of vectors  in the collection.

Base case:  if the number of vectors is $d$ then the collection is a basis already (by standard results).

Now suppose we have proven the result for all collections with $n$ vectors (for $n≥d$).  We want to prove that the result also holds for collections with $n+1$ vectors, so take such a collection, $S=\{v_1, \cdots, v_{n+1}\}$.  Since $n+1>d$ there must be a linear dependence between these vectors.  Let's say we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_iv_i=0$$ and that not all the $\lambda_i$ are $0$.

Let $j$ be the greatest index such that $\lambda_j\neq 0$.  Then we can write $$v_j=\sum_{i\neq j}-\frac {\lambda_i}{\lambda_j}v_j$$

It follows that we can eliminate $v_j$ from the collection without changing the span.  But the set $S'=S-\{v_j\}$ has only $n$ elements so the inductive hypothesis applies to it, and we conclude that $S'$ contains a basis for $V$.  But since $S'\subset S$ that basis is also a subset of $S$, and we are done.

Note:  if your spanning set $S$ is infinite then it also must contain a basis. To see that, take some basis $\{e_1, \cdots, e_d\}$ for $V$.  Since $S$ spans we knwo we can write each $e_i$ as a $\textit {finite}$ linear combination of vectors in $S$. Choose one such expression for each $e_i$. Define $S^*\subset S$ to be the (finite) subset of $S$ consisting of all the vectors from $S$ that are used in those expressions and apply the above to $S^*$.

Comment: Yes, it is assumed to be in a finite dimensional vector spaces as the questions does not mention anything about the infinite dimensional. "If a set S of vectors is linearly independent in a vector space V, then it is possible to add zero or more vectors to S to create a basis for V". I wrote that as a mean to validate my understanding of the concept of independence, basis and spans. As linearly independent vectors in a finite dimensional sets will span the whole vector space,  adding another vector to the independent set will not help create a basis I assume.

Comment: I completely understood this answer. Thank you for your time !

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Note that your second question, about extending the independent collection to the basis, is different than the one I answered.

Comment: Yes, I am still wondering if that would work. I will continue to read about it. In the case it is not clear I will post a question

Comment: Try an inductive approach, as in my argument above.  This time you have to apply induction to the "co-dimension".  That is, if the dimension is $d$ we assume your collection has $d-i$ elements and apply induction to $i$.